# Pandas, value error

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, pivot

i have the following data in an excel:

```
SCENARIO    DATE    POD         AREA    IDOC    STATUS  TYPE
AAA   02.06.2015    JKJKJKJKJKK 4210    713375  51         1
AAA   02.06.2015    JWERWERE    4210    713375  51         1
AAA   02.06.2015    JAFDFDFDFD  4210    713375  51         9
BBB   02.06.2015    AAAAAAAA    5400    713504  51        43
CCC   05.06.2015    BBBBBBBBBB  4100    756443  51       187
AAA   05.06.2015    EEEEEEEE    4100    756457  53       228
```

and i want to achieve the following pivot:

```
SCENARIO   STATUS   TYPE  COUNT(TYPE)
AAA        51       1     2
                    9     1
           53       228   1
BBB        51       43    1
CCC        51       187   1
```

I have tried the following, but it aggregates for every single column, also, the type appears as a floating point, ie :

```
SCENARIO STATUS TYPE
E01      51     1.0     23   23   23   23       23       23   23   23     2
                4.0     89   89   89   89       89       89   89   89     8
                13.0    21   21   21   21       21       21   21   21     2
                20.0    57   57   57   57       57       57   57   57     5
                29.0     5    5    5    5        5        5    5    5
```

I would like just one "count" to appear here, one column. 
This the code i ve tried:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("MRD.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet3") 
print (df.column.values)

# The following gave ValueError: Cannot label index with a null key
# dfi = df.pivot('SCENARIO)

# Here i do not actually need it to count every column, just a specific one
table = df.groupby(["SCENARIO", "STATUS", "TYPE"]).agg(['count']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas.out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) with specify column in `[]` if **dont** need count `NaN`s:

```
table = df.groupby(["SCENARIO", "STATUS", "TYPE"])['TYPE'].count()
print (table)
SCENARIO  STATUS  TYPE
AAA       51      1       2
                  9       1
          53      228     1
BBB       51      43      1
CCC       51      187     1
Name: TYPE, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), column specify is not necessary, but difference is it count `NaN`s also:

```
table = df.groupby(["SCENARIO", "STATUS", "TYPE"]).size()
print (table)
SCENARIO  STATUS  TYPE
AAA       51      1       2
                  9       1
          53      228     1
BBB       51      43      1
CCC       51      187     1
dtype: int64
```

If need columns from `MultiIndex Series`:

```
table = (df.groupby(["SCENARIO", "STATUS", "TYPE"])['TYPE']
           .count()
           .reset_index(name='COUNT(TYPE)'))
print (table)
  SCENARIO  STATUS  TYPE  COUNT(TYPE)
0      AAA      51     1            2
1      AAA      51     9            1
2      AAA      53   228            1
3      BBB      51    43            1
4      CCC      51   187            1
```

```
table = (df.groupby(["SCENARIO", "STATUS", "TYPE"])
           .size()
           .reset_index(name='COUNT(TYPE)') )

print (table)
  SCENARIO  STATUS  TYPE  COUNT(TYPE)
0      AAA      51     1            2
1      AAA      51     9            1
2      AAA      53   228            1
3      BBB      51    43            1
4      CCC      51   187            1
```

Last if dont need write first column called index to `excel`:

```
table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: Could you help me with how i could go to add subtotals per scenario and status/scenario?

Comment: Can you create new question with sample data and desired output? Thanks.

Comment: Or do you need `df['new'] = df.groupby(["SCENARIO"])['COUNT(TYPE)'].transform('sum')` ?

Comment: I will post a different question (even though its slightly similar) so i can accept/upvote your answer. I m sorry in advance, its just that i personally find the documentation for pandas a bit confusing. Thank you.